# cuda-memcheck not reporting correctly when using in-device malloc() and cudaMalloc() in the same program

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, cuda, memory-leak-detector

I was using the cuda-memcheck's leak-check on a small test file I made to test some functionality I wanted to implement in a program I'm working on, and I found that it is not reporting some very obvious memory leaks on global memory, when I have calls to both `cudaMalloc()`(from host code) and `malloc()`(from device code). It seems the call to device `malloc()` is breaking the functionality of `cuda-memcheck`.
I'm running this on NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050(compute capability 6.1), on Windows 10. I have CUDA v10.2, using the Visual Studio C++ compiler(`cl.exe`). A friend of mine also ran this on his Arch Linux system, with CUDA v9.1, and an NVIDIA GeForce MX150(compute capability 6.1), with identical results. Here's the code I used:

```
#define gpuErrchk(ans){ gpuAssert((ans), __FILE__, __LINE__);}

__host__
inline void gpuAssert(cudaError_t code, const char *file, int line, bool abort=true)
{
    if (code != cudaSuccess)
    {
        printf("GPUassert: %s %s %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(code), file, line);
        if (abort) exit(code);
    }
}

class intarr {
    public:
        static const int arr_size = 5;
        int arr[arr_size];
        __host__ __device__ void print() {
            printf("arr = {");
            for(int i = 0; i < arr_size; ++i) {
                printf("%d", arr[i]);
                if(i != arr_size-1){
                    printf(", ");
                }
            }
            printf("}\n");
        }
};

class Tester {
    __device__ void print_yay() {
        printf("yay = {");
        for (int i = 0; i < yay_size; ++i) {
            if (yay[i] == 'A' || yay[i] == 'a')    printf("%c", yay[i]);
            else    printf("-");
            if (i != yay_size - 1) {
                printf(", ");
            }
        }
        printf("}\n");
    }
    public:
        intarr * b0;
        char * yay;
        const int yay_size;
        __host__ Tester() : yay_size(2) {
            intarr b;
            yay = nullptr;
            for(int i = 0; i < intarr::arr_size; ++i)    b.arr[i] = i;
            gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&b0, sizeof(intarr)));
            gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(b0, &b, sizeof(intarr), cudaMemcpyDefault));
        }

        __device__ void lol() {
            yay = (char *)malloc(2*sizeof(char));
            new(yay) char[2]{'a', 'A'};
        }

        __device__ void print() {
            b0->print();
            print_yay();
        }

        __device__ void cleanup() {
            if (yay)    free(yay);
            yay = nullptr;
        }

        /*__host__ ~Tester() {
            if(b0)        cudaFree(b0);
            b0 = nullptr;
        }*/
};

__global__ void kernel(Tester * d_t) {
    d_t->lol();
    d_t->print();
    d_t->cleanup();
}

int main() {
    printf("Tester = %zu bytes, intarr = %zu bytes\n", sizeof(Tester), sizeof(intarr));
    Tester h_t;
    Tester * d_t;
    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_t, sizeof(Tester)));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_t, &h_t, sizeof(Tester), cudaMemcpyDefault));
    kernel<<<1, 1>>>(d_t);
    gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceSynchronize());
    gpuErrchk(cudaGetLastError());
    gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceReset());
}
```

Here it is pretty clear that there are 2 memory leaks, as I'm not freeing `d_t`, as well as the member pointer `b0`, using `cudaFree()`. I compiled this using `nvcc.exe -G -Xcompiler /Zi -o cuda cuda.cu`, and then ran `cuda-memcheck.exe --leak-check full cuda.exe`. The output:

> ```
> ========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
> Tester = 24 bytes, intarr = 20 bytes
> arr = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}
> yay = {a, A}
> ========= LEAK SUMMARY: 0 bytes leaked in 0 allocations
> ========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
> ```

When I removed the call to `d_t->cleanup()` from the kernel, the output:

> ```
> ========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
> Tester = 24 bytes, intarr = 20 bytes
> arr = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}
> yay = {a, A}
> ========= Leaked 2 bytes at 0x7016fff24 on the device heap
> =========
> ========= LEAK SUMMARY: 2 bytes leaked in 1 allocations
> ========= ERROR SUMMARY: 1 error
> ```

The 2 byte leak is most probably because `d_t->yay` is not freed from the device heap.(I haven't checked explicitly if that is the exact leak though, I'm just guessing)
Now, when I also removed the call to `d_t->lol()`, as well as `print_yay()` from `Tester::print()`(basically remove the code that allocates memory to `d_t->yay` from device heap using device `malloc()` and the code that reads `d_t->yay`), so now the kernel looks like:

```
__global__ void kernel(Tester * d_t) {
    d_t->print();
}
```

the output:

> ```
> ========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
> Tester = 24 bytes, intarr = 20 bytes
> arr = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}
> ========= Leaked 24 bytes at 0x501200200
> =========     Saved host backtrace up to driver entry point at cudaMalloc time
> =========     Host Frame:C:\WINDOWS\system32\nvcuda.dll (cuMemAlloc_v2 + 0x173) [0x19d7a3]
> =========     Host Frame:D:\cudatest\cuda.exe (cudart::driverHelper::mallocPtr + 0x3e) [0x4017e]
> =========     Host Frame:D:\cudatest\cuda.exe (cudart::cudaApiMalloc + 0x3e) [0x1ff1e]
> =========     Host Frame:D:\cudatest\cuda.exe (cudaMalloc + 0xdd) [0xc31d]
> =========     Host Frame:D:\cudatest\cuda.exe (cudaMalloc<Tester> + 0x1d) [0x48e2d]
> =========     Host Frame:D:\cudatest\cuda.exe (main + 0x3b) [0x4894b]
> =========     Host Frame:D:\cudatest\cuda.exe (__scrt_common_main_seh + 0x10c) [0x4a1b8]
> =========     Host Frame:C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNEL32.DLL (BaseThreadInitThunk + 0x14) [0x17bd4]
> =========     Host Frame:C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll (RtlUserThreadStart + 0x21) [0x6ce51]
> =========
> ========= Leaked 20 bytes at 0x501200000
> =========     Saved host backtrace up to driver entry point at cudaMalloc time
> =========     Host Frame:C:\WINDOWS\system32\nvcuda.dll (cuMemAlloc_v2 + 0x173) [0x19d7a3]
> =========     Host Frame:D:\cudatest\cuda.exe (cudart::driverHelper::mallocPtr + 0x3e) [0x4017e]
> =========     Host Frame:D:\cudatest\cuda.exe (cudart::cudaApiMalloc + 0x3e) [0x1ff1e]
> =========     Host Frame:D:\cudatest\cuda.exe (cudaMalloc + 0xdd) [0xc31d]
> =========     Host Frame:D:\cudatest\cuda.exe (cudaMalloc<intarr> + 0x1d) [0x48e5d]
> =========     Host Frame:D:\cudatest\cuda.exe (Tester::Tester + 0x6d) [0x48edd]
> =========     Host Frame:D:\cudatest\cuda.exe (main + 0x2b) [0x4893b]
> =========     Host Frame:D:\cudatest\cuda.exe (__scrt_common_main_seh + 0x10c) [0x4a1b8]
> =========     Host Frame:C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNEL32.DLL (BaseThreadInitThunk + 0x14) [0x17bd4]
> =========     Host Frame:C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll (RtlUserThreadStart + 0x21) [0x6ce51]
> =========
> ========= LEAK SUMMARY: 44 bytes leaked in 2 allocations
> ========= ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors
> ```

Clearly, it showed the correct leaks.
Also, I noticed something else that's weird. When my kernel is:

```
__global__ void kernel(Tester * d_t) {
    d_t->print();
    d_t->cleanup();
}
// Also print_yay() is commented out in Tester::print(), to prevent cuda-memcheck
// from terminating prematurely due to an illegal memory access error
```

which is basically the same as the one above, as `d_t->cleanup()` wouldn't do anything anyway, the output:

> ```
> ========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
> Tester = 24 bytes, intarr = 20 bytes
> arr = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}
> ========= LEAK SUMMARY: 0 bytes leaked in 0 allocations
> ========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
> ```

It still stopped showing the leak!
Is this some issue with `cuda-memcheck`, or is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: Please pay close attention to the [documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-memcheck/index.html#supported-error-detection) for leak detection. Especially "precise" versus "imprecise". There are limits to what the tool can resolve, and I would guess you are hitting those here

Comment: My suggestion would be to file a bug at developer.nvidia.com

Comment: @talonmies I did read that section, and as I understood it, device heap memory leaks(which are imprecise) are reported with lesser information than cudaMalloc memory leaks(which are precise), as the imprecise ones are directly reported by the hardware, not found by the memcheck tool. I couldn't see anything mentioned there about not reporting certain errors, and I thought it should certainly not fail to report a precise error.